# 18.04 can't connect to protected WLAN - instant disconnect: reason 6

Tags: wireless, 18.04, connection

I'm having problems with my wireless card.
I can connect to networks that are not protected by a password. But if the network is protected by a password I'm asked for the PW over and over again.
(On my Win10 installation I don't get asked for the PW it just keeps on trying.)

I've run the network troubleshooting script (complete output can be found at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CZpAfJtD)) and I believe the error is related to:

```
[  852.427952] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'FRITZ!B0x Fon WLAN 7390' [AN8]>
[  852.432270] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'FRITZ!B0x Fon WLAN 7390' [AN8]> (try 1/3)
[  852.434770] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  852.438251] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'FRITZ!B0x Fon WLAN 7390' [AN8]> (try 1/3)
[  852.442326] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'FRITZ!B0x Fon WLAN 7390' [AN8]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[  852.445755] wlp2s0: associated
[  855.455859] wlp2s0: deauthenticated from <MAC 'FRITZ!B0x Fon WLAN 7390' [AN8]> (Reason: 6=CLASS2_FRAME_FROM_NONAUTH_STA)
```

This keeps on repeating.

Apparently Reason 6 means:

6   Class 2 frame received from nonauthenticated STA    Client attempted to transfer data before it was authenticated.

This is a little bit strange to me as in line 3 the output was 'authenticaded'.

Thank you for your attention.
If you know what I could do to fix this please let me know.

Comment: Your router(s) are configured incorrectly. Do you have more than one wireless router in your area (neighbors or yours)? Do you have a dual-band router? If so, are the two wireless bands set for the same network name/password?

Comment: My wireless is provided by my landlord so I have no control over the router configuration. However my other laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 can connect just fine. So the router seems to be working just fine in principle. There are multiple routers in the area. And I believe it has dualband, as it is listed in two identical instances with the same password. On the old laptop i can connect to either on the new one to none.

Comment: In **terminal**, do `sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan`, find the ESSID for the two wireless networks, locate the line that looks something like **Cell 01 - Address: 04:A1:51:38:C4:71**, one for the 2.4ghz and one for the 5ghz networks. Write down the MAC numbers. Open your wireless network config for your wireless network, and enter one of the MAC addresses into the BSSID field. Try to connect. If it doesn't connect, try the other MAC address in the BSSID.

Comment: This seems to have no effect at all. I can enter both MAC addresses in both connections and they behave in all 4 cases like before. I keep getting the password-prompt over and over and over.

Comment: It's possible that the spaces and special characters in the network name could be causing the problem. See if you can temporarily get the landlord to change that and see what happens.